# ef code first связка virtual Entity property и ID в другой таблице (подобие one to zero or one связи)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class FirstEntity
{      
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SecondEntity SecondEntity { get; set; }
}

public class SecondEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? FirstEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

Вот набросок моих entity. Нужно получить связку, 1к 0..1 
Каким мне реализовать (И возможно ли это вообще) так что бы когда я присваивал.

```
FirstEntity.SecondEntity = new SecondEntity { id = new Guid.NewGuid() };
```

У меня в базе автоматически записывался `SecondEntity.FirstEntityId` того FirstEntity в котором прилинковали `SecondEntity`, и когда я удалю или изменю `FirstEntity.SecondEntity`, что бы `FirstEntityId` удалялся, или перезаписывался соответственно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом мне правильно реализовать структуру, либо возможно нужно настроить эту связку через `DbModelBuilder`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Связь по полю, не являющемуся первичным ключем, не является связью 1:1 с точки зрения EF.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а о какой связи 1к1 идет речь? или я не правильно вопрос понял? разве речь не о том случае когда у сущности могут быть дополнительные свойства(а могут не быть).

Comment: @Bald56rus, ну, 1:0..1, а не 1, разницы никакой. Если поле не является первичным ключем - связь сразу же становится 1:* или *:*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в контексте работы с базой данных в метод `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` добавляем следующий код:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FirstEntity>()
   .HasOptional<SecondEntity>(a => a.SecondEntity)
   .WithRequired(a => a.FirstEntity)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

в модель `SecondEntity` добавляем:

```
public virtual FirstEntity FirstEntity { get; set; }
```

Comment: нет, уже пытался таким способом, при добавлении вашего modelBuildera у меня в таблице firstEntityId и SecondEntityId вообще пропадают, даже после их добавления опционально (т.е добавляю проперти) они не линкуются, т.е при присваивании одного свойства, второе автоматически не присваивается

Comment: @JULIK о каком `SecondEntityId` идет речь? я о нем не писал, и даже не думал. То что я написал вполне неплохо работает как связка 1..1 при этом SecondEntity не обязателен.

Comment: Речь идет о том, что после того как я добавляю в OnModelCreating ваш код, у меня почему то пропадает SecondEntityId  и FirstEntityId если они явно не указаны в виде проперти, но даже если указаны связка не происходит

Comment: @JULIK Речь о том, что их там и не должно быть, они вяжутся по ключу, причем у родительского класса ключ автоинкриментный например, ну или как в вашем случае Guid, то у второго класса ключ берется из первого, то-есть они равны